# Specify generics class where T should be subclass of other type

Tags: c#, generics

Here is what I'm trying to do, not even sure if possible..

I'm creating `BaseViewModel<T>` and I want it to accept types inherited from `Entity`

Consider this code:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : NotificationObject, INavigationAware
{

public T MyEntity;

public SomeMethod()
{
MyEntity.SomeEntityProperty = SomeValue;
}

}
```

So, I want to say that my `T` inherited from `Entity` and therefore I KNOW that it will have SomeEntityProperty.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Salvatore's answer is totally correct, I just wanted to describe the concept a little better.

What you need is a "generic type constraint"; to specify that the type used as T must conform to certain behaviors (such as being derived from an object or interface more derived than Object), thus increasing what you are allowed to do with that object without further casting (which is generally to be avoided in generics).

As Salvatore's answer shows, GTCs are defined using the "where" keyword:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> :
    NotificationObject,
    INavigationAware

    where T : Entity;
{
   ...
```

This GTC basically states that any T must derive (however remotely) from Entity. This allows you to treat T as if it were an Entity (except for instantiation of new Ts; that requires an additional GTC), regardless of how more or less derived the actual generic parameter type is from Entity. You can call any method that appears on Entity, and get/set any field or property.

You can also specify that:

- The type must be a class (`where T:class`), or alternately must be a ValueType (`where T:struct`). This either permits or prevents comparison and assignment of a T instance to null, which also allows or prevents use of the null-coalescing operator `??`.
- The type must have a parameterless constructor (`where T:new()`). This allows instantiations of Ts using the `new` keyword, by ensuring at compile-time that all types used as Ts have a constructor that takes no parameters.

Comment: Sorry to necro a 6 year old response but how does one specify a particular constructor signature? e.g. T:new(int,float). This is the only reference I can find to this capability and the compiler doesn't seem to like it but it definitely seems like a useful constraint if there is indeed a way to define it.

Comment: @SebAndraos - Not possible; that was a mistake in the original post. The only generic constraint relating directly to constructors is the default constructor constraint requiring a parameterless constructor of any T. You can define other constraints that would allow you to ensure that a particular constructor (or factory method) signature existed, but it wouldn't be as universal as "where T:new(int, string)".

Answer (score 16):

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> :
    NotificationObject,
    INavigationAware

    where T : Entity
{

    public T MyEntity;

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        MyEntity.SomeEntityProperty = SomeValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use the `where` keyword:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : NotificationObject, INavigationAware
    where T:Entity
{
...
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using the [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) constraint:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : NotificationObject, INavigationAware
    where T : Entity
{
    public T MyEntity;

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        MyEntity.SomeEntityProperty = SomeValue;
    }
}
```