# Set Property Type to a Type of a Class

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono

In C# it is possible to set the type of a property to `Type`, like such:

```
public Type Target { get; set; }
```

I would like to do pretty much that, except be a little more specific about what kind of types are allowed, such as only subclasses of a certain abstract class. I tried the following, but for obvious reasons it does not compile:

```
public typeof(Page) Target { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Yes, it's called generics

Comment: I'm confused of what you want. You don't want a property that holds instances of a subclass of a type you want a property that allows vales of `Type` that is a subclass of `Page`? No you can't do that.

Comment: @RonBeyer your comment is closest thing (generics). If you write an answer using generics, perhaps using where (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810550/specify-generics-class-where-t-should-be-subclass-of-other-type), I will mark it as correct.

Comment: In C#, `Type` is not generic so you can't do that. I think you ask this question because Java's `Class<E>` class is generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyClass<MyType>
{
   public MyType MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```